# Could not query AD without distinguished name in SearchRequest?

Tags: c#, active-directory, distinguishedname

I am running a test Active directory and am trying to query with ldap. I created a searchrequest object with distingueshed name empty and a filter this is throwing noSuchObject error code with "object does not exist" message. I am only getting this from my test AD , if I use my company's production AD I am not getting exception, just a response with no hit. What do I need to change in my test AD to see similar behaviour ?

Comment: Can we see the query?  You need to add classes/schemas that the production AD is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the other answers. I solved my problem by using GC port 3268 instead of DC port 389 in the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// and with specified last name (surname)
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.Surname = "Willis";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `Surname` (or last name)
- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Answer (score 0):

@marc_s answered by giving you a way of searching

Back to your question, just a recall :

A LDAP search is

1. The nod from which you ask to begin the search (in your case the DN of your OU)
2. The scope of your search (base, onelevel, subtree)
3. The filter of your search ((objectClass=group))
4. The attributes you want to retreive

In you case it works when your ADSI layer is able to find a default Domain. So I think that you have to create a real LDAP-SEARCH request en perhaps also give credentials.